# Testing API with Curl

Tags: api, http, curl, lamp

I'm writing an API with Flask.  Testing with a browser works great:

http://stuff.com/login?username=test@test.com&password=testpassword

returns what I expect.

However, I tried typing this into curl two ways (forgive the ignorance, new to LAMP)

curl http://stuff.com/login?username=test@test.com&password=testpassword

curl -i http://stuff.com/login?username=test@test.com&password=testpassword

Unfortunately, the variables in the query aren't making it to the server, as my error message is similar to passing:

http://stuff.com/login?username=

Help?

Comment: I am not sure but is this helping:
http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request
?

Comment: Try surrounding the url with single quotes:  `curl 'http://stuff.com/login?username=test@test.com&password=testpassword'`

Comment: That got it.  Thanks.  Feel free to answer and I'll verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason is because your shell is evaluating the `GET` arguments you are using, instead of passing them on as a string.  To prevent this, use single quotes around the request url.  For example:

```
curl 'http://stuff.com/login?username=test@test.com&password=testpassword'
```